# PDF Image from Binary in MTOM

Tags: c#, pdf, soap, mtom

I am making a custom `HttpWebRequest` call to a GSoap web service that returns an XML + XOP envelope which contains a PDF Image as binary.

I am grabbing the response and taking the binary code in between the boundary string.

Finally, I convert the binary to `byte[]` and save it as a PDF.

Now, I can see the PDF metadata so the encoding was right, but when I try to open it, I get `insufficient data for an image` error and the image inside the PDF is not displayed.

I am converting the binary string via this:

```
retBytes = System.Text.Encoding.UTF8.GetBytes(modStr);
```

Where modStr is the string starting with `%PDF-1.1` and ending with `%%EOF`. Do I need to do more encoding/decoding so that the image shows up granted I can see everything else (pages/metadata, etc)?

Comment: PDF can contain binary data; it should never be treated as a `string`. The fact that it has a lot of parts in it that look like text is irrelevant.

Comment: @MarcGravell: Well, since I was able to get the PDF metadata right, I am thinking I am on the right path, I just need to see why the image inside the PDF didn't display.

Comment: @MarcGravell: I also tested the byte array with PDFSharp `TestPdfFile()` function which returns a valid version number so the headers are correct.

Comment: no, there's a non-sequitur there. Being able to get the PDF meta/headers only tells you: that you were able to get the meta/headers. Perhaps the meta/headers is/are always text based. That **does not** mean that the entire PDF is text based (and quite simply: it is not). If you use a string encode on PDF data ***you will corrupt*** the PDF (usually)

Comment: more to the point, if you are using MTOM, I would expect to see this going simply as a `byte[]`; that is, after all, what MTOM ***is for***. If you use a `byte[]` rather than a `string` it should work fine. It is a flat out mistake to use `string` here

Comment: to put that in context, if I took an HTTP request (or response), and decoded it as text, I could quite genuinely be able to say "look, I can get the headers". But: I will have *irretrievably corrupted* the `jpg` that it was carrying in the body. Being able to read headers does ***not*** prove that you are doing it the right way.

Comment: @MarcGravell: the problem with this particular MTOM package is that this web service returns a complex object, not a byte[] and C# does not parse the XOP object properly, that's why I was trying different routes

Comment: PDF is an annoying format in that it can accept changes between line-endings almost everywhere, except for those stream objects in the file that are somehow binary encoded (ZIP or JPEG compressed images for example). On top of that the readers (like Adobe Acrobat) are very forgiving and can fix many common problems that exist in the file. Make sure your writing to the file doesn't change the line-endings in the file...

Comment: @DavidvanDriessche and the easiest way not to change line-endings: *treat it as a blob*

Comment: @Victor whatever you do to extract the PDF, never handle it as text.  It isn't text.

Comment: would there be a way to somehow extract the PDF binary from the SOAP response without actually damaging the image binary?